# Add column in dataframe from make list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

> a*.csv

```
 D        A     B     E       F

park    KOREA   1   SUM1    hello1

michel  France  3   SUM3    hello3

park2   USA     4   SUM4    hello4
```

> b*.csv

```
A       B   C

KOREA   1   2020

KOREA   2   177

France  3   2020

USA     4   43

SPAIN   7   67
```

> example

```
 D        A     B    C(add)  E        F

park    KOREA   1   2020    SUM1    hello1

michel  France  3   2020    SUM3    hello3

park2   USA     4   3       SUM4    hello4

park3   SPAIN   7   67      SUM5    hello5

park4   USA     8   177     SUM6    hello6

park5   KOREA   11  584     SUM7    hello7

park6   DEN     5   43      SUM8    hello8
```

I edited the content and then restored it
because the answer didn't solve it and I solved it myself

I'll end the question after commenting it solution

but I chose one answer to close this question

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you solved your own question - great! but don't edit it to say "solved"; either close it (by accepting another answer, by answering your own question, or just by closing it) - or if the question is not interesting, delete it.

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin Thank you for explain about Stack Overflow,  I will tried just by closing and delete it but I can't it's possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the merge() function.

```
try_a = glob.glob('a*.csv')
try_b = glob.glob('b*.csv')
lst_a = []
lst_b = []
for (i,j) in zip(try_a,try_b):
 lst_a.append(i)
 lst_b.append(j)
df_a = pd.concat(lst_a)
df_b = pd.concat(lst_b)
df_a.set_index('d', inplace= True)
df = pd.DataFrame.merge(df_a,df_b, how = 'inner', left_index = True).reset_index()
```

I hope it works!!

Comment: It's have a error messages -> Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'set_index'